Need Help Making ROS 2 Humble Packages Compatible with Foxy (Student Project)
I'm currently a student (mechanical engineering) working on a project with ROS2 (integrating a Radar Sensor in ROS2), and I could really use some advice. I’ve been working with packages that were originally built for ROS2 Humble (provided by the Company), but now I need to make them compatible with ROS2 Foxy (University uses foxy because of other Sensors). Since Foxy is an older version, I’ve noticed some differences and challenges when trying to get everything working.
My questions:
Dependencies:
How do you handle the dependencies when downgrading from Humble to Foxy? Are there any tools or tips to make sure everything works with the right versions?
Code Changes:
What are the typical code adjustments needed for this kind of downgrade? Are there any major changes in the APIs between Humble and Foxy that I should be aware of?
Resources:
Are there any guides or references that could make this process easier? I’ve looked through some documentation, but any extra advice would be super helpful!
